# google map android v2 MarkerOption icon cannot accept StateListDrawable

Tags: android, google-maps-mobile, statelistdrawable

I wanna add a StateListDrawable as a marker icon like this :

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(xy).title("Marker").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.state));
```

however, it give me an null pointer exception, any workaround ?

```
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at maps.y.bw.a(Unknown Source)
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at maps.y.bw.b(Unknown Source)
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at maps.y.bw.a(Unknown Source)
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at maps.y.ae.addMarker(Unknown Source)
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IGoogleMapDelegate.java:167)
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addMarker(Unknown Source)
12-06 18:52:51.152: E/AndroidRuntime(3264):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
```

thx !

Comment: Did you make sure that the map is initialized, per the documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory Beyond that, the name `BitmapDescriptorFactory` suggests that it is designed for use with bitmaps, not composite drawable resources like a `StateListDrawable`.

Comment: hi, is that any workaround? what I wanna do is to make it enabled to show difference state (e.g show green color when user focus the marker, show back to original color when lost focus etc.